# Calculate a date column in a Google Spreadsheet based on other columns

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have made a Google Sheet for handling my medication.

In column A, I have a dropdown of medication that I take. The time I initially take the medication isn't important, but what is important is when I take the next pill and it is different for each one. One pill, after taking it, I need to take the next one 6 hours later while another, I don't take until 24 hours later. I go to sleep at different times every day so when I take the initial pill depends on when I wake up or when I eat breakfast or such. The most important one is the one that I need to wait 6 hours before I can take it again. That is my pain pill.

So far, I have the sheet setup so that I have the drop down list of medication and column 2 inputs the exact date and time that I take the pill. The 3rd column, I have a formula that is set to take column 2 and add 6 hours to it which is not correct for all meds, so that is where I need help. I know it can be done, but I don't know who to ask. If I can get it so that the 3rd column will see what medication I chose then depending on which one it will put the time that I need to take the next one. Here is what I have so far but using a formula to add 6 hours which applies to all and that is why the formula won't work:

**Worksheet**:

```
Medication        Pill-taken-at        +6 hours
----------------------------------------------------------
Mycoxofloppin     2018-03-17 12:44     2018-03-17 18:44 
Maryjaneaspliff   2018-03-16 04:20     2018-03-16 10:20
```

**Script**:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var timezone = "GMT-5";
  var timestamp_format = "yyyy-MM-dd   hh:mm";
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var start = 2;
  var end = 4;
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 1){
    ss.getRange(row, start).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this is a bit of an unorthodox question, but can you create a public google spreadsheet and share the link in your question above?  I'm sure someone would be willing to give you a hand (if not myself).

Comment: @Gerik I agree. Though unorthodox, IMHO, this question presents a clear issue and sufficient research.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AjrU1DXsmS2aUlXh5f4BVEcavt4SjNiiDJtWTnSP6hQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is what I have made. This is a copy. with this code. function onEdit(e) {
  var timezone = "GMT-5";
  var timestamp_format = "yyyy-MM-dd   hh:mm";
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var start = 2;
  var end = 4;
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 1){
    ss.getRange(row, start).setValue(new Date());
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a table: Say

```
Y1: Pill Name    Z1:(Interval(hrs))    
Y2: Dumiliyuop   Z2: 6    
Y3: WhacyHittlir Z3:18
```

C2:

```
=B2+VLOOKUP(A2,Y:Z,2,0)/24
```

Comment: If you go to somps.imgur.com you can see the screenshit of my script page that I'm looking at. I know that it probably is a simple thing for you, but when someone who has no idea about it, its not as easy. I was thinking that I could hit return just before all of the var's, but I don't know if that will screw it up or not.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. :P  It seems to work. C shows a note about an alarm set for the correct time. I will see if I get the email. From the looks of it, I'm pretty sure I will get the email. I will study this and try my best to learn from it. Thank you for your help. Would u mind sending me a screenshot of the way the code should look so that I can try to learn correctly? I'm pretty sure the way I pasted it, although it works, I might not have made it look proper and am willing to learn how best to set it up. If what I have is good enough then I'm ok. I will do my best to get familiar with it

Comment: I had to make a small modification. Hey I debugged it! I know, easy stuff for u but at least I'm starting to make sense of it. I had to change C2. The meds and hours are in H:I instead of G:H. I've been making all of the sheets the same so that when I compare in order to learn, they are all apples to apples. The previous sheets were H:I so I just changed that and it seems to work. I've taken two meds. At first, the time was 6 hours but after looking and catching that, I fixed it and it automatically fixed the time. It's looking good!!!!!! Thank you for everything. I will study it and learn!

Comment: I got the email! YES!

Answer (score 1):

`Range::getValue` gets you the value of a cell in Google Sheets' API. I'm assuming that your cells are typed as `DateTime` so `getValue()` will give you a JavaScript `Date` value that you can easily perform date-calculations on.

You don't need to worry about timezones or date formats if your cells are typed correctly. ("typed" as in "data-type", not "keyboard typing").

```
function onEdit(event) {

    var range = event.range;
    if( range.getColumn() != 1 && range.getColumn() != 2 ) {
        // Only update when column 1 or 2 are updated.
        return;
    }
    var rowNumber = range.getRow();

    var ss = event.source.getActiveSheet();

    var drugName     = ss.getRange( rowNumber, 1 ).getValue();
    var lastDoseTime = ss.getRange( rowNumber, 2 ).getValue();

    // Validate info in the edited row:
    if( !drugName ) {
        console.warn( "No drug name specified in col 1, row %d.", rowNumber );
        return;
    }

    if( !( lastDoseTime instanceof Date ) ) {
        console.warn("No valid date value in col 2, row %d.", rowNumber );
        return;
    }

    var hoursUntilNextDose = getTimeBetweenDosesInHours( drugName );
    if( !hoursUntilNextDose ) {
        console.warn("No dose time available for the drug \"%s\".", drugName );
        return;
    }

    var timeUntilNextDoseInMilliseconds = hoursUntilNextDose * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    var nextDoseUnix = lastDoseTime.getTime() + timeUntilNextDoseInMilliseconds;
    var nextDoseTime = new Date( nextDoseUnix );

    ss.getRange( rowNumber, 3 ).setValue( nextDoseTime );
}

function getTimeBetweenDosesInHours( drugName ) {

    // toUpperCase() is more robust than toLowerCase(): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx
    switch( drugName.toUpperCase() ) {
        case "MYCOXOFLOPPIN"  : return 6;
        case "MARYJANEASPLIFF": return 4.20;
        case "GYM"            : return 365 * 24;
        default               : return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you, I've corrected my answer, and I've added more error checks with explanations.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AjrU1DXsmS2aUlXh5f4BVEcavt4SjNiiDJtWTnSP6hQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, I created this as ofthnder@gmail.com and I guess this is using Whadayathinking@gmail.com to post the message. I thought that I had logged out of whadayathinking, but I guess I hadn't. Sorry.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I didn't get to this earlier. I tried it and there is an error in line 4, File "Code"

Comment: ***Update - Sorry. I didn't copy all of the code; however, after copying all of the code, I tried putting in BUPRENORPHINE 8 MG (which I substituted into your first name) and MARYJANESPLIFF into the data validation field and I don't get any results of time stamp or next dosage...

Comment: I want to thank you for helping me. I couldn't seem to get it to work for me but the other user gave me a pretty easy fix that I am going with. I will still look at this code and see if I can figure out where I was going wrong with it. It looks like something that would have been useful if I had figured out what to do on my side of it. Thank you!!!